# How to overload += with 2 LinkedLlsts

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, doubly-linked-list

I don't understand how to take 2 LinkedLists, and add the objects inside to eachother.
i.e, Add nodes of LinkedList2, to LinkedList1.

My current code is what I've tried, but I dont know how to access mutliple objects, because cygwin tells me I can only have one argument.

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList firstList, secondList;
    firstList += secondList;

}
```

```
void LinkedList::operator +=(LinkedList lst)
{
    Node* temp = lst.get_head();
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        Node::value_type student = temp->get_data();
        "WHAT DO I ADD HERE".addToTail(student);
        temp = temp->get_next();
    }
    delete temp;
}
```

Lets say in the "WHAT DO I ADD HERE", because Cygwin says I can only pass in one object, I'd like to be able to add the objects in the second list, to the first list.
But I don't understand whats being passed, whether its list 1 or 2, and then how to add to the other.

Comment: How about `this`?

Comment: Where would I add ```this```

Comment: `this->addToTail(student);`

Comment: or (*this).addToTail(student) if you need to use the dot. :-)

Comment: @Stoychevski Show the class definition. It seems this part ""WHAT DO I ADD HERE"." should be empty.:)

Comment: You don't need `delete` here. It doesn't cause any immediate issues since `temp` is null at that point, but it would if it weren't.

Comment: Thanks for all the help fellas. Currently this is an assignment, and I don't currently need any failsafe checks as the data is already pre-given so it's never null, but one of the marking scheme is deleting basically everything that could/needs to be deleted, you're probably right since it's null, but I think it looks pretty, but I'll ask the tutor when I get back in.

Comment: @Stoychevski A few weeks (or days) from now, you're going to see a stray `delete` like this and your first thought will be "that's probably a bug", not "now *that's* pretty!".

Comment: This is very easy, all you have to do is the following. I do this myself, occasionally, when faced with a complicated task: just get a blank piece of paper. Write down short, logical sentences, in plain English, which describe a step-by-step process for logically implementing this task. When finished, review it for accuracy, [then schedule an emergency appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). After your rubber duck approves your plan of action, simply take what you wrote down and translate it directly into C++. Problem solved!

Comment: The `delete temp;` is as irritating as it would be to have a prior `temp = temp;` or `if (temp != nullptr) temp = nullptr;`. After `while (temp != NULL) { }` (and no `break` inside body) you should expect nothing else and `delete temp;` should result in something no-op-like. If you want to be extra sure or self-convincing then how about a `assert(temp == nullptr);` instead.

Comment: Btw. `+=` (like every assignment) is a binary operator. Overloading is not allowed with plain functions (like for non-assignment operators) but only as class member (allowed for non-assignment operators as well). For class member operator overloads, the left hand side is the object, the operator is called for i.e. it becomes `this` and the right hand side becomes the single argument. That's why only one parameter (the other is implicit). Btw. like in every member function, `this->` can be dropped if there is no ambiguity.

Comment: `this->addToTail(student)` will presumably work.   The `this->` is typically optional (implied when calling a member function within a member function of the same class).

Comment: @Stoychevski `operator +=(LinkedList lst)` -- Please note -- Passing by value requires the type to have correct copy semantics.  Either pass-by-reference, or make sure that `LinkedList`'s can be copied without issue (i.e. a user-defined copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor, or ensure that all members can be copied without issue).  If it isn't copyable, then you may have runtime issues later on.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at what your question is asking you should also understand that when adding "LHS += RHS" you are taking the left and adding the right. This means you are passing in the RHS (right hand side) in your case it seems to be secondList. If you use "This->addToTail" should be fine. Also you will not need Delete as it's just a local variable and is not taking memory from the Stack.

Comment: What is This in this expression This->addToTail? And why is it required?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow First I should clarify "This" does not ALWAYS have to be used, but you will find situations where it must be used. When using "This" it refers to the Object being Manipulated and is just a pointer. "This" is extremely helpful in a lot of situations in this specific example when you call "firstList += secondList" the "This" in that function would be a pointer to the object firstList.

Comment: Thanks guys, only being 5 weeks in to learning c++, this has been super helpful. I've got to do a -= overload as well, but I'm hoping I can apply this knowledge and basically make the same function but make a few edits.